# How can I convert string to get ASCII numbers in python?

Tags: python, ascii, encode

I have this code:

```
str = "text"
x = str.encode('ascii')
print(x)
```

I got this:
b'text'

I want to get this:
"116 101 120 116" as string.
I want the solution like [here](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/) I got.

Comment: `print(list(x))` gives you the integers. `print(*x)` would give you space-separated integers.

Comment: Please don't redefine builtins like "str" and others. It may break more complex code. Example : `isinstance('anything', str)` will not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map to map each character to its ascii value

```
str1 = "text"
list(map(ord,str1))
```

If you need as a string output

```
str1 = "text"
' '.join(list(map(str,map(ord,str1))))
```

Comment: Seems this is faster than the below method by almost a multiple of 2.

Answer (score 5):

```
print ([ord(c) for c in 'text'])
# [116, 101, 120, 116]
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):

> Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string. For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97, ord(u'\u2020') returns 8224. This is the inverse of chr() for 8-bit strings and of unichr() for unicode objects. If a unicode argument is given and Python was built with UCS2 Unicode, then the character’s code point must be in the range [0..65535] inclusive; otherwise the string length is two, and a TypeError will be raised.